# Symfony ivory google map photos url

Tags: google-maps, symfony

I want to display a photo of a google place. I'm using below code to get the information about a place

```
$request = new PlaceDetailRequest($placeID);
$response = $this->container->get('ivory.google_map.place_detail')->process($request);
```

Its Working fine.
 With `$response->getResult()->getPhotos()[0]->getReference()` I get the reference to the first photo.

Now to get the real URL of this photo I have to call 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=PHOTOReference&key=YOUR_API_KEY

To get this I using below code

```
$requestPhoto = new PlacePhotoRequest($placeID);
$responsePhoto = $this->container->get('ivory.google_map.place_photo')->process($requestPhoto);
```

and get below error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "ivory.google_map.place_photo". Did you mean this: "ivory.google_map.place_detail"?
```

Can anybody help me? Or: How can I get the URL on a different way?

Answer (score 0):

OK, found the problem: It was a misconfiguration of the config.yml. I had an empty line before 'place_photo'

`ivory_google_map:
    place_detail:
        client: httplug.client.default
        message_factory: httplug.message_factory.default
        format: json
        api_key: 
    place_photo:`